# Number of items in result in ASP repeater with Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, repeater

I'm working with Sitecore `ascx` file, and got something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="NavRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="item">                      
             <img src="<%# ((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem).Fields["Image Url"] %>" width="360" height="420" alt="">
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate></SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Can't figure out, how to get total number of elements from `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item`.

I was also wondering how to retrieve given item in collection - like item no 2 ?

Comment: Sitecore.Data.Items.Item it's just a class, you can't get item number 2. What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have something like :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="NavRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptGallery_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="item">
     <sc:fieldrenderer id="fldGalleryItemImageThumbnail" runat="server" fieldname="ImageUrl" disablewebediting="true" />   
      </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
   <SeparatorTemplate></SeparatorTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

On Page_Load you will have:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          rptGallery.DataSource = listofitemyyouwanttoshow;
          rptGallery.DataBind();
    }
```

On rptGallery_ItemDataBound event you will have:

```
    protected void rptGallery_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
     {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Item item = (Item)e.Item.DataItem;
              //you can check index here of item
            if (item != null)
            {
                var fldGalleryItemImageThumbnail = e.Item.FindControl("fldGalleryItemImageThumbnail") as FieldRenderer;
                if (fldGalleryItemImageThumbnail != null)
                {
                    fldGalleryItemImageThumbnail.DataSource = item.ID.ToString();
                    fldGalleryItemImageThumbnail.Parameters = String.Format("width={0}", 360);
                }
               }
            }
          }
    }

  I hope it helps you .
```

Answer (score 1):

It's on the data source of your repeater in C#:

So if your C# is:

```
NavRepeater.DataSource = someData;
```

Then the length is `someData.Length` or `someData.Count()` based on its type.

For getting a specific item at a location:

```
Item second = someData[1]; // per 0-indexing
```

Or based on type, can also be:

```
Item second = someData.ElementAt(1) // per 0-indexing
```

Answer (score 0):

You would get these from the enumerable that you are binding you repeater to.